# Android Studio throws exception while running Flutter App

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle, exception

When I run the flutter app it throws this error below

> > Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi 7 in debug mode...
> > Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> > Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found   at
> > java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1567)  at
> > java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1462)     at
> > java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1469)     at
> > java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.(ZipFile.java:1274)  at
> > java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1237)     at
> > java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.(ZipFile.java:727)
> > at
> > java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:844)
> > at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:247)     at
> > java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:177)  at
> > java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:191)  at
> > org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)    at
> > org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)    at
> > org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)    at
> > org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)    at
> > org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.
> > access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)   at
> > org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
> > at
> > org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
> > Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I have my android device connected with USB debugging on. I don't know what's wrong.

Tried Solutions :

- [Flutter App Stuck at Running Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59516408/flutter-app-stuck-at-running-gradle-task-assembledebug?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top). Any of them didn't work for me
- Tried `flutter doctor`. It says no issue found.
- Tried Updating Android Studio.

PS: I am new to flutter any help or suggestions will be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60899075/flutter-exception-in-thread-main-java-util-zip-zipexception-error-in-opening

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help. But I found a solution somehow.

Comment: I just deleted the .gradle folder in C:\Users\(Username), and it worked. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is mainly due to a currupt or incomplete file in the .gradle folder in your users folder. just find it and delete it and then run it again but this time around make sure you are connected to the internet to re download it again. if you are on a mac you can remove it with

```
cd ~
rm -rf .gradle
```

Comment: I just deleted the .gradle folder in C:\Users(Username), and it worked. :)  I have mac.