# Flutter Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found

Tags: flutter

I am facing such error after running flutter run command

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1607)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1497)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1504)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1308)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1271)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:733)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:850)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:248)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:191)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            390,5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: this will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67901965/flutter-gradle-task-assembledebug-failed-with-exit-code-1-zip-end-header-not-fou

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68855690/9610781
hope this solution will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is related to Gradle, this is usually due to corrupt or incomplete Gradle setup

find (.gradle) folder and delete it

then run the application again and wait for new gradle setup to complete